# Urls not working after ssl in django site on nginx

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https

I had a fully functional site at which I converted to be served through https:// using lets-encrypt free certbot using the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04. Now after applying this my django urls for views as well as static files aren't working and I am getting the 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error page which sometimes goes away on reloading the page but then the static files won't load.

I have tried all the solutions I could find to the above problem from various forums but am unable to get it to work probably because I am new to https secure websites.Kindly Help

Thanking you in advance :)

nginx settings file - (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default)

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;

server {
server_name bits-bosm.ml www.bits-bosm.ml;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/sammy/regsoft/regsoft;
    expires max;
}

location / {
     include proxy_params;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/regsoft/regsoft/regsoft.sock;
     limit_req zone=one;
     limit_conn addr 10;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bits-bosm.ml/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bits-bosm.ml/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


gzip on;
gzip_comp_level    5;
gzip_min_length    256;
gzip_proxied       any;
gzip_vary          on;

location ~*  \.(ico|css|js|svg)$ {
    expires 7d;
}


}

server {
if ($host = www.bits-bosm.ml) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = bits-bosm.ml) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name bits-bosm.ml www.bits-bosm.ml;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name bits-bosm.ml www.bits-bosm.ml;
return 301 https://www.bits-bosm.ml$request_uri;
}


server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bits-bosm.ml/fullchain.pem; # managed$
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bits-bosm.ml/privkey.pem; # manag$
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

server_name bits-bosm.ml;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

django settings.py has the following configurations :-

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
`    ]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True

STATIC_URL = 'https://www.bits-bosm.ml/static/'
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Ps: I had chosen option 2 during the certbot setup as shown below (if that helps) -

```
Please choose whether or not to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS, 
removing HTTP access.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
---------
 1: No redirect - Make no further changes to the webserver 
configuration.
2: Redirect - Make all requests redirect to secure HTTPS access. 
Choose this for
new sites, or if you're confident your site works on HTTPS. You can 
undo this
change by editing your web server's configuration.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
---------
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to 
cancel):
```

Update:
My nginx error logs show that nginx is trying to find static files from

```
 "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/main/fonts.css" failed (2: No such file or directory),
"/usr/share/nginx/html/static/pcradmin/js/jquery.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working as expected"?  Are you seeing errors in the Django logs?  Are you seeing errors in the ngix logs?  Are you seeing errors in the browser?  "Not working as expected" is why questions are posted!

Comment: @Gerik editted the question. You can see the error I am getting at https://bits-bosm.ml/register/

Comment: Hey Nikhil, in my experience the cerbot will attempt to edit your nginx config files for you.  Have you reloaded nginx to ensure the latest changes have been loaded?

Comment: Yes sir .. I have tried reloading/restarting both my nginx as well as gunicorn services without any errors.

Comment: Apologies if I'm mistaken here, but you've got the the ssl certificates includes in your NGINX file twice and I suspect https settings configured in the server on the bottom are ignoring the static settings you have configured at the top.

Comment: @Gerik commenting the bottom 2 server blocks still gives the same error

Comment: Hey Nikhil, actually I meant the other way around: move the static directory into the https server section like this: https://gist.github.com/mjumbewu/7fa64e83e02d613f4daa031d66d6c247

Comment: The same 403 error still shows up .. when it goes after reloading the static files aren't able to load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168797/discussion-between-gerik-and-nikhil-khandelwal).